# Is there an alternative expression for 'the third/fifth wheel on the wagon'?

Tags: expressions

Does anyone know of an alternative to this expression that is more common, please?

Not a 'gooseberry' as that implies a romantic connotation.

Just a way of describing being the 'extra' person in a situation.

Comment: *Two is company, and three is a crowd.* (said by a suitor when attempting to woo his love and some third party is tagging along or interfering, aka "scram, kid!").

Comment: I would say that the person would be "adding weight" to an encounter/meeting/whatever, but I've tried googling it and can't find anything whatsoever. I didn't invent this one... at least I don't think so..

Comment: How about "spare"?

Comment: What's with this "on the wagon"? The phrase as I know it is just simply "a third wheel".

Comment: Some, if not all, of the following are probably more accurate when describing WHY a person is considered to be a third wheel: persona non grata; social pariah; someone who cramps your style; a hanger-on; an uninvited guest; a dweeb; a social misfit; an odd duck; socially inept; a superfluous person; redundant; expendable; a cocklebur; intruder; a pest; an outcast; a social leper; dead weight; an irritant. Don

Comment: Odd man out....

Comment: 3rd wheel is pretty common..

Answer (score 1):

***[Spare part](https://www.quora.com/What-does-stand-like-spare-parts-mean-in-English)***

If you are the spare part at a party you are surplus to requirements, the 'extra' person.

As explained in an answer from Quora:

> We use it in British English. For example if you're at a party and
>   everyone else is having fun and talking to others and you are standing
>   alone you might feel like a spare part.

Comment: A coarser version (also British) is "_a spare prick at a wedding_" ([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_spare_prick_at_a_wedding)) – "_A person who is out of place or has no role in a particular situation._".

Answer (score 0):

**be surplus to requirements** -

> to be no longer needed.
>   *Many very experienced workers have been told they are surplus to requirements.*
>
> Synonyms and related words.
>   Not wanted or needed:unnecessary, redundant, unwanted...
>    - https://www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/dictionary/british/be-surplus-to-requirements

Answer (score 0):

**de trop**

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not wanted; unwelcome. ‘she had no grasp of the conversation and felt
>   herself de trop’
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/de_trop)